# Java: тернарный оператор, нюансы его работы

Tags: java, null, тернарный-оператор, autoboxing

Пусть имеем такой код:

```
System.out.print((true ? 1 : null).getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Все скомпилируется и результат будет

```
Integer
```

Залезая в документацию по тернарному оператору, имеем:

> The type of a conditional expression is determined as follows:
>
> If the second and third operands have the same type (which may be the
> null type), then that is the type of the conditional expression.
>
> If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and
> the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion
> (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.
>
> **If one of the second and third operands is of the null type and the**
> **type of the other is a reference type, then the type of the**
> **conditional expression is that reference type.**
>
> Otherwise, if the second and third operands have types that are
> convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric types, then there are several cases:
>
> - If one of the operands is of type byte or Byte and the other is of
>   type short or Short, then the type of the conditional expression is
>   short.
> - If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte, short, or char,
>   and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.28) of type int
>   whose value is representable in type T, then the type of the
>   conditional expression is T.
> - If one of the operands is of type T, where T is Byte, Short, or
>   Character, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.28) of
>   type int whose value is representable in the type U which is the
>   result of applying unboxing conversion to T, then the type of the
>   conditional expression is U.
> - Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand
>   types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type
>   of the second and third operands.
> - Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion
>   (§5.1.13) and may perform unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> **Otherwise, the second and third operands are of types S1 and S2
> respectively. Let T1 be the type that results from applying boxing
> conversion to S1, and let T2 be the type that results from applying
> boxing conversion to S2.**
>
> **The type of the conditional expression is the result of applying
> capture conversion (§5.1.10) to lub(T1, T2) (§15.12.2.7).**
>
> [Источник](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

Я выделил жирным два пункта, которые, как мне кажется, могут иметь отношение к происходящему в примере.
Вопрос, что именно происходит и как в данном случае?

Первый выделенный пункт - типа компилятор пытается применить эти правила, видит, что один из операндов null.. но второй то int, дай ка я его автоупакую и будет ссылочным типом. И таком образом, результирующий тип по правилу становится Integer.

Но почему тогда момент "дай ка я его автоупакую и будет ссылочным типом" не указан в правиле? Может быть это подразумевается, так как такое поведение описано еще где-либо?

Или здесь все же применимо второе выделенное правило?
Честно, я с ним еще не разобрался, там довольно много чтива и несколько раз надо по ссылкам в процессе понимания перескакивать, это будет небыстро.
А именно, что такое "capture conversation" и "lub(T1, T2)".

Но я уже не могу понять, мы имеем, что S1 == int type, S2 == null type, тогда T1 == Integer, но что тогда с null и чем является T2?
Т.е. получается, это правило не применимо.

Интересует, что же именно тут происходит?

Comment: Первый точно говорит про reference type, которым int не является.

Comment: 'lub' - это ['least upper bound' (супремум)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4), для негенериков - ближайший общий супертип (а для генериков у меня лапки). Про родственные связи 'null type' посмотрите там же

Answer (score 1):

второе, по логике и экспериментально, потому что

```
System.out.print((true ? 1 : new Object()).getClass().getSimpleName());
```

тоже выдает `Integer`

**дополнене:**

```
    System.out.println((true ? 1 : null).getClass().getSimpleName());
    System.out.println((true ? 1 : new Object()).getClass().getSimpleName());
    System.out.println((false ? 1 : new Object()).getClass().getSimpleName());
    System.out.println((true ? 1 : new String()).getClass().getSimpleName());
    System.out.println((false ? 1 : new String()).getClass().getSimpleName());

=>
Integer
Integer
Object
Integer
String
```

Comment: тогда я совсем запутался, ...and let T2 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to ... Object ???

Comment: Так, к слову, типом возвращаемым оператором в вашем примере будет Object. Даже если там написать new String(). предполагаю, что capture conversion так работает, приводит к общему предку.

Comment: метод getClass() возвращает класс объекта, все правильно. Если объект строка, то класс будет срока. Но тип возвращаемой ссылки оператором будет Object.

Comment: Object будет только если там реально сидит экземпляр Object'а, см. дополнительные тесты в ответе.

Comment: тип объекта и тип ссылки - это разные вещи. то есть, (ссылка типа Object).getClass().getSimpleName() вернет "String", если фактически объект - строка, полиморфизм же

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что тернарный оператор выбирает тип из рантайма в зависимости от условия. Следовательно соответствующее пробразование типов выполняется к исходному выражению. Поскольку у вас `true` в выражении, то второй операнд просто не используется и преобразование типов не осуществляется.

> Но я уже не могу понять, мы имеем, что S1 == int type, S2 == null type, тогда T1 == Integer, но что тогда с null и чем является T2? Т.е. получается, это правило не применимо.

Совершенно верно, поскольку правило использует оба выражения, а у вас оно *одно*.

Comment: я читал, что тип возращаемого значения тернарным оператором определяется на этапе компиляции...

Comment: именно так путем отбрасывания недоступного кода

Comment: не согласен, потому что упрощенная версия System.out.println((1).getClass().getSimpleName()); не скомпилится вообще!

Comment: @Ramiz согласен такой код компилироваться не будет

Comment: хм. посмотрел в байткод. действительно компилятор выбрасывает тернарный оператор если в в условии константа.

Comment: System.out.print((Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : null).getClass().getSimpleName());

Comment: Насколько я понял, поскольку тернарный оператор может использоваться в сложных составных выражениях,  компилятору нужно сразу понимать, какой тип будет возвращаться. Поэтому и есть эти правила. В моем комментарии выше, компилятор на момент компиляции не знает, каким будет значение Math.random(), но тем не менее код компилируется.

Comment: "именно так путем отбрасывания недоступного кода" -- тип возвращаемого значения описан в этих правилах документации. Про ваше утверждение там ни слова. Более того, если бы оно было верным, то вернулось бы int, а не Integer, на мой взгляд.  Поэтому я не могу посчитать ваш ответ верным

Comment: Здесь вы привели совсем другой пример кода, который существенно отличается от того, который в вопросе. Поэтому компилятор будет рассматривать тип ненулевого операнда, упакованного или завернутого типа.

Comment: Long l = true ? 1 : null; -- Компилятор выдаст "Error:(25, 23) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to java.lang.Long" , это я к тому, что даже с константой в первом операнде вычисляется тип возвращаемого значения на основе 2 и 3 операнда

Comment: Long l = 1; -- компилятор в этот раз выдаст "Error:(25, 18) java: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.Long"

Comment: И наконец, Long l = true ? 1 : new Short((short)1); выдаст "Error:(25, 23) java: incompatible types: short cannot be converted to java.lang.Long", что опять же указывает, что несмотря на явное true , вычисляется результирующий тип на основе обоих операндов по правилам указанным в вопросе

Comment: попробуйте int оно должно подойти, но компилятор все равно выдаст ошибку.